# How to install a Ad Hoc provisioning app on windows itunes?

Tags: iphone, app-store, itunes, provisioning, adhoc

I drag the .mobileprovision and app.zip file in the list of applications in itunes, I also get add-cursor, but if release the mouse-button nothing happens. the list is still empty, whats wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way I know to do this is to get the .app file in Mac, put it into a folder called "Payload". Then you have to ZIP this folder and change its name from "Payload.zip" to "MyAppName.ipa". Mac will ask if you are sure you want to change the extention, select "YES". Now you can drag and drop this file into itunes.

There's no other way to do it afaik. Windows makes problems with the macosx "fork" files (if you open the .app file there is a folder named "_MACOSX" or similar... and windows breaks this).

Answer (score 1):

Unzip the app.zip. You will get a folder, e.g. MyApp.app. Now drag that folder into iTunes and it should be ok.

Comment: I have tried it, but it is still not working. The apple-documentation says that the app must be compressed on a mac.

Comment: first darg the file ending with .mobileprovision and the add your application which will look like a folder with name ending with .app e.g "yourApplicationName.app"

Comment: Yeah, sure, so you build your app on the mac and you zip it. You go to the AppName/build/Distribution-iphoneos folder and there you will see a file named AppName.app (Finder shows it as file but in reality it's not). Right-click on this AppName.app file and select Compress "AppName.app". Then you will get a zip which you can then send to the people who have Windows. They can use the procedure I explained above to install. I've used this procedure successfully many many times.

Comment: This is how I USED to do it.  It appears you have to use the payload method described above with iTunes 10.

Comment: Wow, didn't know about that. So on Windows doesn't it work then?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned - unzip it, but don't forget to drag the .mobileprovision too
If that doesn't work, check back in your provisioning so it's set to the right device.
Common mistake.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.markj.net/iphone-ad-hoc-distribution-windows-mac/

You can save all this trouble though, but making a zip archive in the first place that doesn’t have the Mac resource fork.  BetterZip is a handy Mac app that will do this for you. That preferences setting ‘Remove Mac specific stuff from archives’ keeps __MACOSX out of the zip, and the resulting zip will install on Mac and Windows. Another way to do this is to unzip in windows yourself, find the correct app folder, and re-zip.

Answer (score 0):

Ive had this problem before. I'm pretty sure there can be no white spaces in the name as well... double check that before you try to add it.